# Silverlight can't access cross domain WCF service

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a `Silverlight` app hosted on server A, and a `WCF` service hosted on server B on IIS 6. Server B disallows any non-https connections (not that it doesn't rewrite them.. they just fail).

in wwwroot for server B I have a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
```

Looking at proxy traffic, I can now see the silverlight app requesting mydomain/clientaccesspolicy.xml and returning an HTTP 200 with the contents, however, silverlight then gives a security exception.

I have tried many variations of the clientaccesspolicy.xml files and even crossdomain.xml examples floating around the internet to no avail.

Additionally, the SL app works if I install it instead of run it through the browser.

I am wondering if this is a SL 5 bug?

Note that this is a follow-up to my original question I asked earlier, where I was unable to see the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` request go out (but I can now and it still doesn't work).